# Time complexity of lookup and then insertion in a std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>>

Tags: c++, stl, time-complexity, complexity-theory

So I have a graph (std::map) that stores strings as the keys and the values are sets of strings (adjacency lists for each node in a graph):

`std::map<std::string, std::set<std::string>> graph`

My insertion code is simply:

`graph[from].insert(to)`
where *from* and *to* are both strings. So I insert *to* in the set of strings associated at the key *from*.

For the average and worst-case time complexities for this insertion bit of code, I think they are O(x*log(V) * y*log(n)), where x is the length of the string *from*, y is the length of the string *to*, V is the number of nodes in the graph, and n is the number of edges in the graph (I included the string lengths because I think we also have to consider std::string comparisons which are O(length of either string))?

And the best-case time complexity is either the same as the average/worst-cases or it's O(x*y), which occurs if we get lucky and the root node of the red-black tree for the map and sets implementations are the strings *from* and *to*, respectively -- although, I'm the least confident about this one.

I'd appreciate some help. Thanks.

Comment: Might want to get with you classmate that asked this exact question a few minutes ago.

Comment: @sweenish I don't see any question similar to this one asked recently, but I did ask about standard insertion/lookup in a map/set a couple of hours ago here. Now, this is a bit more complicated of a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time complexity is in terms of something, for example key comparisons. Finding a key in a `std::map` or `std::set` is in `O(log n)` key comparisons. If your key comparison function compares two strings character by character, then you can say that finding a key in this case is in `O(s log n)` with `s` the average size of the key strings (and not just the key you are trying to find).

In your scenario, you first find `from` in `O(s log V)` and then insert `to` in `O(t log N)`. `s` is the average size of the key strings in the map, `t` is the average size of the key strings in the specific set (the set that corresponds to `from`), `V` is the size of the map (or number of vertices), and `N` is the size of the specific set.

These are two separate steps, which is why I say "specific set" and not "all the sets in the map", and so the total time complexity is simply `O(s log V) + O(t log N)` or `O(s log V + t log N)`.

If you don't know the characteristics of the set you will insert to in advance, then you could do some more averaging and end up with `O(s log V + u log(E/V))`, where `u` is the average size of the key strings in all the sets in the map, and `E` is the number of these keys (number of edges). Reminder: this complexity is in terms of character comparisons. It may or may not be useful, especially because it has four variables.

Comment: Thank you, that's pretty much what I was thinking. One more question: for the best case time complexity, would it be O(s + t*log(N)) where s is the length of the 'from' string and t is the length of the 'to' string? Essentially the case that the map's root key (red-black tree implementations) is the 'from' string so that is O(1)*string search complexity?

Comment: @Slash The first step is indeed one key comparison in the best case, so `O(s)`. The second step can be just two key comparisons if you provide a hint or if the insertion happens to be at the correct place in the tree, so `O(t)`. In any case, the two still add together.